# Failed to create tab for chat by calling MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm experiencing an issue below when I create a tab for chat by calling MS Graph API:
*/chats/19:38e62161-7b34-4d12-adda-c57756249b08_a37fa161-9541-41ef-b46b-d4a8d1a08fd4@unq.gbl.spaces/tabs*

The Graph Explorer is as following: [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Here is the post body:

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "contentUrl": "https://xxx/index.html?#/fioritab/https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx",
        "entityId": "",
        "removeUrl": null,
        "websiteUrl": "https://xxx"
    },
    "displayName": "Display Name",
    "teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web"
}
```

Here is the error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Apps not allowed for federated chat thread",
        "innerError": {
            "message": "Apps not allowed for federated chat thread",
            "code": "AccessDenied",
            "innerError": {},
            "date": "2023-07-26T08:04:28",
            "request-id": "xxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried my best to find this error message-related by googling and inside microsoft doc but unfortunately, nothing can be found.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, anyone can help me out?

Thanks in advance.